# discord.py send pm on member join

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a bot that sends a user a pm when he joins the server.
I searched and I found that to d this you need to have intents enabled, but when I enable them it gives me an error "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed". I can't figure out what exactly not working, I've seen somewhere that regenerate the bot token helps but it didn't help for me.

this is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os


# Load token
env_path = os.path.join(Path('.'), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
TOKEN = os.environ.get('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is running...')
    print(f"Name: {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"ID: {bot.user.id}")
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    welcome_msg = f"hi {member}"
    await member.send(welcome_msg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to DM the user as soon as they join a server, you should did `{member}` and the argument "member" is just a guild version of The user, and to display the name with `member.name` there for it will show the Member's name on the message.

Here is your Fixed Code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks # add tasks if you're going to do tasks.
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os


# Load token
env_path = os.path.join(Path('.'), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
TOKEN = os.environ.get('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is running...')
    print(f"Name: {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"ID: {bot.user.id}")
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    welcome_msg = f"hi {member.name}" # You don't need to define the message.
    await member.send(welcome_msg) # You can do await member.send("message") instead of defining it.

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Hope this helped. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives me the "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed".

Comment: 1. You have to have the intents on for your bot in https://discord.com/developers

2. Do you have 2 `on_member_join` events?

Comment: Thank you! I turned on the intents in the developers panel and it worked.